# how draw foreground in flame_tiled

Tags: dart, flame

I need help to draw map created from Tiled (.tmx)

version info

```
flame: 1.5.0
flame_tiled: 1.9.0
```

what I want is to draw background first, then player, then foreground.

I have 4 layer for now,

- foreground (tile layer) (top layer).
- spawn (object layer).
- housing (tile layer).
- land (tile layer).

already working with drawing background and player and foreground with this code. but I need to save 2 file of map data.

```
final currentMap = await TiledComponent.load(
  '$mapName.tmx',
  Vector2.all(16),
);
add(currentMap);

final spawnPointObject = currentMap.tileMap.getLayer<ObjectGroup>('spawn');
for (final spawnPoint in spawnPointObject!.objects) {
  final positions = Vector2(
    spawnPoint.x + (spawnPoint.width / 2),
    spawnPoint.y + (spawnPoint.height / 2),
  );
  switch (spawnPoint.class_) {
    case 'player':
      _player = MyPlayer(
        anchor: Anchor.center,
        current: 'idle',
        position: positions,
        size: Vector2.all(16),
        name: name,
      );
      add(_player);
      break;
  }
}

final currentForeground = await TiledComponent.load(
  '${mapName}_foreground.tmx',
  Vector2.all(16),
);
add(currentForeground);
```

I can draw from object layer, but take soo much case will be hard for update later..
so is there any way to draw only 1 layer with flame_tiled.?

this is sample image, I want my player to draw behing the roof when played.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VTLI.png)

```
- already try with layer object and drawing base on object id, one by one. but take so much effort.
- try with 2 save file, but still hard to maintain (used now)
```

Comment: By design `ObjectLayer` is supposed to contain meta-data that you can consume to spawn game entities. Flame cannot decide what to render using ObjectLayer on its own. So unfortunately you'll have to add a case for each type of object that you want to spawn on object layer.

Comment: The other part of the problem is that objects spawned by your code are rendered after the TiledComponent finishes rendering all its layers. So even if you've placed the ObjectLayer in between the background and foreground layers in Tiled, your code will still render objects from ObjectLayer on top of everything. Unfortunately Flame hasn't exposed APIs to inject custom objects while TiledComponent is rendering itself.

Comment: One possible solution is to render all houses, trees, building, etc as individual components. This will allow you to control the `priority` of each one of them. So if you set priority for player as 1 and house as 2, your player will be rendered behind the house. But be aware that with this approach you'll have to constantly keep updating the player priority to make sure it renders in front of in back based on where the player is standing in comparison to the house. You can watch this video to understand it better: https://youtu.be/UfKMgHbaGow?t=692

Comment: thanks for the response, well using `ObjectLayer` take so much code to draw, for now I still using 2 save file. this working but I need 2 save file for map, and this just to much work for me, btw if you are the same person, I use the "Simple Platformer" video to creating the base of my game.

Answer (score 0):

My personal conclusion about this problem is that flame_tiled is not flexible enough, so the best thing it can do for you is to parse map files. If you need a flexible rendering, you going to implement it on your side, because flame_tiled renders everything as a big flat batch of sprites.

Probably you can do a fast hack by rendering the RenderableTiledMap twice. At first pass you disable "roof" map's layers (see "setLayerVisibility" function) and renders everything into a Picture / Image and wraps it into a component with "ground" priority.
Than you enable "roof" layer and disable "ground", then do the same rendering into another Picture / Image and wraps it into another component with "roof" priority.

Trying to solve this problem, I have made two solutions. One is simpler, another is more complicated and still in development / debug stage:

1. https://pub.dev/packages/flame_tiled_utils - with this you can render every map's tile as a component into separate layer with given priority. Exactly what you want, but you need to create some additional classes to describe your map's tile types.
2. https://github.com/ASGAlex/flame_spatial_grid - allows to do the same, but with better abstraction level. Also helps to avoid problems of the previous library (slow rendering on large maps). But it is still in heavy development, sometimes I broke something, sometimes fix...

Sorry for such "longread" answer =)